# Spring mongo - Sum fields from array amd check greater than

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have this object:

```
{
  budgets: [
    {
      amount: 200
    },
    {
      amount: 100
    }
  ]
}
```

What query can I make to count the amount of documents whose budgets sum (200+100, in this case) is greater than 100?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$gt": [{ "$sum": "$budgets.amount" }, 100] }})
```

with Spring Mongo query syntax:

```
@CountQuery("{ $expr: { $gt: [{ $sum: '$budgets.amount' }, 100] } }"
```

Comment: I want to count the amount of documents whose sum of budgets.amount is greater than what I specify, 100 in this example. So in this example I want to do like "count the documents whose budges.amount aum (300) is greater than 100"

Comment: yes,i've tried it in mongo shell and works but I need it with spring query language. I've translated it to this: @CountQuery("{ $expr: { $gt: [{ $sum: 'budgets.amount' }, 100] } }")

Comment: @Wrong Apologies. I do not know about the syntax for spring.

Comment: Okay I forgot the '$' in front of 'budgets.amount' now it works. Thanks, this helped me! @CountQuery("{ $expr: { $gt: [{ $sum: '$budgets.amount' }, 100] } }")